# GWT Internationalization to Arabic (RTL language)?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, arabic

I have a problem (supposed to be a GWT feature) when i internationalize my Webapp to a RTL language. Basically, the GWT feature mirrors the interface to RTL and I don't want that to happen.

How can I prevent GWT from automatically mirror my interface and just keep translated strings?

Here is my *.gwt.xml code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE ... >
<module rename-to='blah'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/> 
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/> 

    <extend-property name="locale" values="pt"/>
    <extend-property name="locale" values="es"/>
    <extend-property name="locale" values="ar"/>

    <source path="client"/>
    <source path="shared"/>

    <entry-point 
        class="EntryPoint"/>

    <!-- Remote services   -->

</module>
```

Regards

Comment: explain elaborate..What is actual issue

Comment: The problem is that when I change the language to Arabic, the interface is automatically mirrored (ie: things on the right go to the left and vice-versa). 

I want that just the strings change, like when we change from english to spanish or other LTR language.

Comment: If it helps I'm using GWT 2.7. I don't include any RTL theme.

Comment: Post you code(*.gwt.xml)

Comment: Posted above. Thanks for the help until now.

Comment: *.gwt.xml file is looking correct,inherit     <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>  theme will show LTR theme only even if you use locale=ar..i am unable solve you issue

Comment: Basically it is this RTL support that is causing my problem http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#RTL_support 
Any idea on how to prevent this?

Comment: Just print this"LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()" in sysout in onmodule of apps to check wether its true or false,if its false then its taking LTR theme otherwise its taking RTL theme

Comment: But how that helps me? I know that it is true if I select arabic and false otherwise, but how I prevent it from being flipped when I am seeing in arabic? Is there a way to override this method or other in order to prevent this?

Comment: no.."LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()" should not be true since you included LTR theme it should be false even if you run with &locale=ar(it will just mirror without RTL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunally this is a feature of a number of the GWT widgets. These widgets call `LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()` internally and even if you would somehow change the return value of this call it would then disable the rtl for text also. So that's not an option.

I guess you have 2 options. Firstly, not use widgets that use the RTL check or secondly, when adding a widget check for isRTL yourself and add it in the opposite direction. For example if you add a widget to the `WEST`, add it to the `EAST` when `isRTL()` is true. Both options are not optimal, but I see no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

GWT Support Both RTL & LTR Langauages

- If you want to have LTR(Left to Right) theme then use `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome"/>` (default theme) in `*.gwt.xml`
- If you want to have RTL(Right to Left) theme then use `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.ChromeRTL"/>`in `*.gwt.xml`

In your case If you dont want GWT feature mirrors the interface to RTL then use `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome"/>`

Comment: That is not my problem. I have this inherits:
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/> 
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>

Comment: then what is the problem..explain elaborately

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class called "CldrImpl_ar" in your project under the "com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr" package (you will have to create this package yourself).  The class would contain the following code:

```
package com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CldrImpl;

public class CldrImpl_ar extends CldrImpl {
    @Override
    public boolean isRTL() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This class already exists in the GWT library code but the return value is true there.  Once this standalone class is created, it takes precedence over the one in the GWT library, thus achieving the "overwriting" effect.

This does exactly what you are looking for:

1. No automatic mirror effect when using Arabic
2. Just use the translated strings

The end result is probably not the best experience for the Arabic user, but it does save significant development time if supporting right-to-left is not a high priority for your project..

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. With GWT 2.6.x, you can accomplish this by using deferred binding to force the value of LocaleInfo.isRTL() to false:

```
<replace-with class="org.activityinfo.i18n.shared.CldrImplLtr">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CldrImpl"/>
    <when-property-is name="locale" value="ar" />
</replace-with>
```

You can leave out the `<when-property-is` tag if you want to force this 
for all locales.

And then provide a simple CldrImplLtr class:

```
public class CldrImplLtr extends CldrImpl {

   @Override
   public boolean isRTL() {  return false; }
}
```

There seem to a few funny things, but it seems to be more manageable than supporting a full Right-to-left mirroring of the interface.